# Download photos from camera to tablet/phone

Tags: android

Can you recommend any tool for Android to download photos from camera (MTP/PTP over USB OTG Nikon Coolpix P310)? The only app I found is Camera Importer, but it often fails in the middle and it has no option to continue which is very frustrating.

It doesn't need to be automatic (but I also do not want to spend time selecting each and every file manually), but it needs to support MTP/PTP (not mass storage) and must not require rooted device. MTP/PTP is the only protocol supported by my camera - it cannot be connected as mass storage.

Comment: Would a standard OTG tool (see [my list here](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_storagemedia)) like an OTG file explorer, or an OTG mounter and then use another file explorer, be acceptable?

Comment: Integrated facts from the comments with your question. Last detail: Maybe you add what camera you have? Some ActionCams have specific apps that do a.o. that.